# Gradle initscript block properties

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to reuse external properties in custom `initscript` block inside `init.gradle?`

```
def REPO_URL = 'myRepoUrl'

initscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url REPO_URL
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'some dependency'
    }
}
```

This gives me unknown property error. I have also tried using ext{} like so

```
ext {
    REPO_URL = 'myRepoUrl'
}
```

with the same error. Yet it works in all other configuration blocks I tried so far even inside `init.gradle`. This forces me to duplicate properties for `initscript` block and rest of the configuration.

After a bit more examination it looks like it totally looses any reference to surrounding scope. I don´t even understand why does it behave this way from Groovy standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a hen-and-egg thing.

To execute the init script you need the dependencies that you declared in the `initscript` block. But you try to use something that is only present during the execution of the init script.

So I'd say what you want is not possible. You have to declare it at least twice, inside the `initscript` block and outside. So the best you can get probably is:

```
def REPO_URL = 'myRepoUrl'

initscript {
    def REPO_URL = 'myRepoUrl'
    repositories {
        maven {
            url REPO_URL
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'some dependency'
    }
}
```

Comment: So does this mean that Gradle somehow compiles and executes initscript method without executing surrounding scope? I am relativelly new to Gradle and Groovy and didn´t know this is possible.

Comment: You can hook into the Groovy compilation process and transform Groovy scripts before they are actually compiled with the standard compiler. One of those transformations in this case should be that the `initscript` block is extracted and evaluated before the rest of the script, as the rest of the script needs the dependencies you declare in that block in its classpath for execution, otherwise you would get compile errors as the dependencies are not in the classpath. Hen-and-egg, as I said. :-)

Comment: Great answer to link into a comment to prevent colleagues asking why have I duplicated this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

In your GRADLE_HOME or PROJECT_HOME you can have 2 files.

**gradle.properties** for properties

**init.gradle** for init script

In gradle.properties you can add your params

```
REPO_URL=myRepoUrl
```

Then in init.gradle you can use it:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url REPO_URL
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can the gradle.properties go into $USER_HOME/.gradle ?

Comment: yes, gradle.properties could be placed at project_home or user_home

Comment: Note that Gradle properties are not available inside the `initscript{}` closure within `init.gradle`, as Gradle has not loaded at the point this is called.  See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/properties-for-initscript-block/22427) for a workaround.